# unable to view akka http package in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, akka-http

I am trying to use akka http v10.0.2.  I added akka-http in my build.gradle file (just akka-http, not http-core or any other akka http related dependency).  I tried using the imports below but the 'akka.http.javadsl.server' does not seem available (even though I can see the package when I download the jar file and extract it).  The other packages are visible.  I have tried clearing the IntelliJ cache.  Barring clearing my ivy cache, are there any other steps I can take to troubleshoot this further?

```
 import akka.NotUsed;
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
    import akka.http.javadsl.ConnectHttp;
    import akka.http.javadsl.Http;
    import akka.http.javadsl.ServerBinding;
    import akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpRequest;
    import akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpResponse;
    import akka.http.javadsl.server.AllDirectives;
    import akka.http.javadsl.server.Route;
    import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer;
    import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;

    import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
```

Comment: Did you add the scala version suffix to your dependency? Should look something like "compile(group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: 'akka-http_2.11', version: '10.0.6')" (note the _2.11 bit)

Comment: it was solved after i posted by adding the other akka http dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was resolved by adding all the other akka http dependencies in my gradle build file.  I will try to post the build file here when possible.